# How to fetch data using One to Many relationship using MySql and joins in MySql

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a demo application. I am stuck in a scenario, I am not getting the exact way and query to fetch data from sql database in the following scenario:

I have a table named `RegistrationTable`, this table has a column `RegistrationId` as its primary key. There is another table named `ApplicationDetails`, this table has a column `ApplicationId` as its primary key.

I have referenced `ApplicationId` as Foreign key to `RegistrationId` column.

My requirement is, single user can apply to multiple jobs. job details will be present in `ApplicationDetails` table.

**How can I check to how may jobs the user has applied based on his email id stored in registration table.**

I have a column `Status` in `ApplicationDetails` table, where as soon as user applied to a job I am updating the status column.

I am trying the following query but its not working:

```
SELECT Status FROM ApplicationDetails
INNER JOIN RegistrationTable ON ApplicationTable.ApplicationId = RegistrationTable.RegistrationId
WHERE RegistrationTable.EmailId = "abc@xyz.com";
```

Can any one please suggest me how can I go about this. I am a beginner to SQL. Please do suggest a way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: @ArunKrish no it does not return any value, result is null.

Comment: Is the query executing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the table name in your query to ApplicationDetails. This is what you mentioned in your post

```
SELECT Status FROM ApplicationDetails 
JOIN RegistrationTable ON ApplicationDetails.ApplicationId = RegistrationTable.RegistrationId 
WHERE RegistrationTable.EmailId = "abc@xyz.com";
```

Comment: I have changed it. It returns null value. it does not return any value.

Comment: are you using abc@xyz.com in query?

Comment: it is an example which i specified, I am using an email id value which user enters

Comment: You say "it returns null value. it does not return any value". Can you describe that a little better? You could mean that the query returns no rows at all, or that it returns a row with a NULL value in Status. Which is it?

Comment: @MattGibson Sorry for the late reply, It does not return any value, means it returns no rows at all..

Comment: @Keshav So, either there's no `emailid` in `registrationtable` with that email address, or there is one, but there's no corresponding row in `applicationdetails` where the `applicationdetails.registrationid` is the same as `registrationtable.registrationid`. Or there's something you're not telling us about how you're running the SQL code. Given that you said in your original question that it was executing without errors, but you had the wrong table name, which would have obviously caused a syntax error, I'd guess the latter...

Comment: @Matt Gibson ok. I will check this, the syntax I had corrected it before posting the question, but by mistake I have posted old query. I am running my SQL query in a xampp server. There is one email id in registration table with the specified value. Can you please tell me whether the procedure followed by me is correct or incorrect?